# Highstock timeseries chart is shrinked

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a highstock timeseries chart,but the chart is shrink. There is lot of space left before and after the chart. Also the data labels are missing.[image: chart shrink]

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) parameter for column serie. Morever you can also manipulate [minPadding / maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding) params on axis.